# Scheduling with google calendar api java

Tags: java, web-applications, google-calendar-api

I am developing an scheduling web application with java and google calendar where a user can see available slot and book an appointment. I created a google calendar and I am able to add available time slots to that calendar through java.

Now, I want to give access to all the users of my system and when they click on "available" event they should book an appointment through it.

I am unable to give the permission to all the users.
So, how on user click event I can change the calendar event in google calendar?

This is my code to create an event.

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = Quickstart.getCalendarService();

    Event event = new Event()
        .setSummary("Available Appointment")
        .setLocation("Toronto")
        .setDescription("Appointment Booking");

String calendarId = "primary";
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
return event.getHtmlLink();
```

Edit: A user can log in to my web application and when a user clicks on *schedule an appointment* I am showing Google calendar in which there are events which is labeled as *Available Appointment*. So what I want is when a user clicks on that event they should able to update that event as booked.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you please edit your question so it is more specific?

Comment: A user can log in to my web application and when a user clicks on schedule an appointment I am showing Google calendar in which there are events which is labeled as Available Appointment. So what I want is when a user clicks on that event they should able to update that event as booked

Comment: Ok, that's a lot clearer. What is the question? What doesn't work?

Comment: So I want to give access to the users of my web application to change the name of the event from "Available" to "Booked".

Comment: That is not a question, neither does it explain what's not working. You want to do it - go ahead and do it.

Comment: I tried to give access to google calendar but google calendar ask to copy that event to the user's account and then a particular user can change, a user isn't able to change it in the "booking calendar". So is there any path or anything that can give access to users?

Comment: Change what? There is [calendar sharing and event attendees](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing), but attendees aren't able to update major properties of an event, which makes total sense. So, what is it exactly you want to achieve, and what doesn't work (notice that I'm asking this same question 4th time already).